# Is $GapCVP_{\gamma} \in coAM$ for all $\gamma$?

Tags: lattice

In [this](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/gg.pdf) lecture Regev introduced the Goldreich-Goldwasser protocol (start of page 2) to show that $GapCVP_{\sqrt{n}} \in coAM$. The protocol is really intuitive, but I don't really understand why he doesn't directly show the claim for an arbitrary $\gamma$ instead of $\sqrt{n}$. This protocol seems to work for every $\gamma$ or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the Goldreich-Goldwasser protocol works for any $\gamma > 1$, it is only **efficient** (i.e., it only runs in polynomial time) for sufficiently large $\gamma$, specifically $\gamma \geq \Omega(\sqrt{n/\log n})$. Intuitively, the reason for this (using the notation in Regev's lecture notes) is that the balls $B(0, r)$ and $B(v, r)$ may have very little overlap in the "$v$ is close to the lattice" case if $r = \gamma d/2$ for small $\gamma > 1$.

In recent work with many co-authors, we gave a general analysis of the Goldreich-Goldwasser protocol. See Theorem 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.11693. The protocol runs in roughly $(1 - 1/\gamma^2)^{-n/2}$ time, where $n$ is the rank of the underlying lattice and $\gamma > 1$. (We also generalized the protocol to non-Euclidean norms.)